# android collision detection with bounds

Tags: android, collision-detection

We are trying to detect collision on a image view that is moving across the screen. The problem is we only want a negative reaction when the bottom or left side of the brickRect collides with the top or right of the ballRect. If the ballRect wants to land on the top of the brickRect then NO negative reaction is desired. Our question is how to write the if statements for these three interactions of the ballRect with the brickRect? We understand how to obtain the top bottom and left values We will post that code not sure it adds to the question

```
        Rect brickRect = new Rect();
    brickFOUR.getHitRect(brickRect);

    int BRICKbottom = brickRect.bottom;
    int BRICKtop = brickRect.top;
    int BRICKleft = brickRect.left;
    int BRICKright = brickRect.right;
```

The object here is to have the ballRect jump up and land on the brickRect
If the ballRect jumps and hits the bottom of the brickRect then do what ever
If the ballRect.right intercepts the brickRect.left then do what ever
So how do we turn this logic into code? 
We have looked at numerous post but they all deal with over all detection

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a pair of positions or Rect models, for the before and after movement of the ball and that the position increases to the top and right, then you could write the code as follows:

```
Rect ballBefore = ...
Rect ballAfter = ...
Rect brickRect = new Rect();
brickFOUR.getHitRect(brickRect);

if(ballBefore.top > ballAfter.top
    && ballBefore.top < brickRect.bottom
    && ballAfter.top >= brickRect.bottom) {
    //movement in top direction
    //and position before is below
    //and position after is not
}
if(ballBefore.right > ballAfter.right
    && ballBefore.right < brickRect.left
    && ballAfter.right >= brickRect.left) {
   //if movement is in right direction
   //and position before is left
   //and position after is not
}
```